# Change author separation from English to German - Change in .bst file doesn't work

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, german

For a paper I have to change my whole Tex file set up to German. I use MikTex 2.9 on Windows. All works except the "and" between the different author names in the footnotes and in the bibliography.

I already tried the recommended solution to change this by going through the `.bst` file, but it doesn't work. `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` does not exist in my file and the only place where I found `" and "` was at `FUNCTION {output:write:list}` which doesn't seem right and also did not work when I changed it there. I checked the whole file but I couldn't find any Function code that might fit.

I made the change in the `biblatex.bst` because in the `.bst` folder (MixTex/bibtex/bst) it is the only one that relates to my code. There is no `natbib.bst`, `authoryear.bst` or `biber.bst` like described in the other solutions here in stackexchange.

Maybe I have the wrong `.bst` file? 
Or I made already some adaptations which changed the .bst code?

I also tried the `\renewcommand*{\betweenauthors}{\und}` option in my preamble which doesn't work either.

I only need this change for one single homework, so an easy (maybe dirty) fix would do. 
Here's my minimal working example (hope it's not too long):

```
\documentclass[12pt, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true, bibencoding = utf8, maxbibnames=10, 
            maxcitenames=3, isbn=false, backend=biber, dashed=false,
            firstinits=true, uniquename=init, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Minimalbeispiel_German.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
   \printtext[parens]{% <- space
   \printfield{labelyear}%
   \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }%
}

%usepackage{germbib}
\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}  % Einzug der umgebrochenen Zeile
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5cm}     % Abstand zw. Literaturangaben

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} %% erst Nachname, dann Vorname
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} % Doppelpunkt nach dem letzten Namen
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} %% Trenner zwischen den Namen ein Semikolon
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\space~and~\space} %% Trenner zwischen den Namen ein Semikolon
%\renewcommand*{\betweenauthors}{\und}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{% 
   \ifboolexpr{ 
     test \ifuseeditor 
     and 
     not test {\ifnameundef{editor}} 
   } 
     {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck} 
        {\bibnamedash} 
        {\printnames{editor}% 
    \setunit{\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}% 
      \usebibmacro{#1}% 
      \clearname{editor}% 
      \setunit{\addspace}}% 
     {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash 
      \usebibmacro{labeltitle}% 
      \setunit*{\addspace}}% 
   \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}} 

        \AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}{%
      \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{type}%      %hier einfach auflisten was nicht erscheinen soll
  }%
 }
        \AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{electronic}{%
      \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{type}%      
  }%
 }
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{book}{%
      \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{url}%       
  }%
 }

\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}

\begin{document}
Some Text\footcite[Vgl.][S. 30]{Example2012} and then even more text\footcite[Vgl.][S. 30]{Doe2013}. And continuing with other text\footcite[Vgl.][S. 30]{Professor2000} and more words\footcite[][S. 30]{Professor2000}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file `Minimalbeispiel_German.bib` to go with it:

```
\begin{bibliography}

@ELECTRONIC{Example2012,
  title = {The Top 100},
  year = {2012},
  url = {http://somepage.de/uploads/files/fd3323c9a2.pdf},
  month = {9},
  day = {25},
  editor = {Webeditor, Mike},
  type = {Whitepaper},
  lastchecked = {2013-07-01},
  urldate = {2013-07-01},
}

@BOOK{Doe2013,
  author = {Doe, John and Smith, Jane and Jamesson, James},
  title = {The Quintessence of Everything},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2010},
  address = {New York, London},
   }

 @unpublished{Professor2000,
  author = {Jackson, Jack},
  title = {Book from my Professor},
  year = {2000},
  month = {6},
  type = {Seminar Book},
  note = {Seminar Book},
  timestamp = {2013-07-18}
}

\end{bibliography}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` does not really use `.bst` files anymore, the important files for `biblatex` are `.bbx` (bibliography), `.cbx` (citations), `.dbx` (data model) and `.lbx` (localization) now.
You could say

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

in the preamble, `biblatex` provides a translation of "and" so just use `\bibstring{and}`. But the original definition of `finalnamedelim` in `biblatex.def` is

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

where `\finalandcomma` is empty for German. That means the standard definition will give you the same output and you actually don't need to redefine `finalnamedelim` at all.

---

There is no need for `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}` in the `.bib` file, in fact I am surprised that your `biber` does not complain (I get a warning like `20 characters of junk seen at toplevel`).

---

*edit*: Modernised for `biblatex` 3.8 and above. Please note that the code in the question is for `biblatex` before version 3.3 ([Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)) and that many other idioms can be replaced by more elegant techniques now.

Comment: Perfect! That works! You're right, I just checked my regular .bib file and it does not include `\begin{bibliography}`. Not sure how it ended up in the minimal example. Guess I copied it somewhere.